# How is a Gold Leaf Electroscope charged negatively by induction?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, electromagnetic-induction, photoelectric-effect

I can't quite seem to get my head around this although this is what I think is going on:

**1) To charge by induction a perspex rod must be charged positively, via contact with a cloth removing negative charge (leaving excess positive charge on rod).**

**2) Then the positively charged rod is brought near the zinc plate at the top of Gold leaf electroscope (GLE)**

**3) This attracts opposite charges from the neutral GLE to be brought upwards leaving the positive charge on the gold leaf**

**4) Since there is an excess positive charge on gold leaf there would be repulsive forces (like charges repel), thus rising the gold leaf.**

**5) Then you place your finger on zinc plate to ground it.**

**6) The negative charge is attracted from the earth due to the positive perspex rod - is it?**

*Question - How can the negative charge be attracted, with the presence of the electrons on the Zinc Plate (grounded on)?*

*How does grounding cause electrons to move up into the GLE?*

**7) this will cause an excess of negative charge which repels the negative charge on top (perspex rod still held)**

**8) This charge travels down (due to like charges repel) and the gold leaf starts becoming neutral again.**

**9) When the rod is removed the excessive negative charges spread out and cause the gold leaf to possess a greater amount of negative charge so they deflect (repel again)**

This makes the gold leaf electroscope negatively charged.

Am I correct?